# Is meta.stackoverflow.com the right place to have discussions related to specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a sub-community around [sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore) tags at StackOverflow. I'd like to suggest some rules/recommendations to follow to keep it consistent (naming conventions, for example). And I expect certain portion of discussion.

Is meta the right place for things like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's (almost) the perfect place.

The child meta's are designed to hold discussions about the parent site. It's scope, the tags, whether specific questions should be opened/closed etc.

[Meta.StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) on the other hand is for discussions about issues that affect the whole network, careers, the mobile apps etc.

Comment: Should I tag the questions like this in some special way? 'discussion' seems reasonable, anything else?

Comment: @YanSklyarenko - [meta-tag:discussion] is one of the required tags on meta. The other tags are up to you.